# How to select only first two children of a parent in a mixin with nth-child?, not every first and second

Tags: css, css-selectors, sass, compass

How to select only first two children of a parent (not every first and every second child). In a `.scss` mixin using `nth:child` selector?

Here is my code and it doesn't work because it selects every second `div`. But I need to select only `col_l` as a `:nth-child(1)` and `col_r` as a `:nth-child(2)`.

**html**:

```
<section id="section" class="clearfix">
    <div class="col_l">     <!-- this is div:nth-child(1) -->
        <div class="title">
             Left col
        </div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>  <!-- this div is also selected as a :nth-child(2), but it is wrong -->
    </div>
    <div class="col_r">   <!-- this is div:nth-child(2) -->
        <div class="title">
            Right Col
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

**.scss**:

```
@mixin two-col($width-left, $width-right) {
    @include clearfix;
    div:nth-child(1) {
        float: left;
        width: $width-left;
    }
    div:nth-child(2) {
        float: right;
        width: $width-right;
    }
}

#section {
    @include two-col(714px, 237px);
    background-color: #749675;
    .col_l { }
    .col-r { }
}
```

How to select *only* the first and *only* the second divs? Not every.

Comment: I think you have a typo that may break other things - `.col-r { }` should be with an underscore - `.col_r { }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the child combinator `>` to the selectors in your mixin to ensure you actually select just the children of `#section` and not any further descendants:

```
@mixin two-col($width-left, $width-right) {
    @include clearfix;
    > div:nth-child(1) {
        float: left;
        width: $width-left;
    }
    > div:nth-child(2) {
        float: right;
        width: $width-right;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's the answer. I would also suggest using `nth-of-type` instead of `nth-child` in such situations in case you need an element before or in between the two divs. It's more bulletproof that way.